# get data by linq but have Error when doit this

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this Error

use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.'](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.%27)

this my code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP3cJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHh4w.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE1AA.png)

i want get Employee name

this path on the images

TBEmployeePc > TBEmployee > EmployeeName (i want get this "EmployeeName")

any ideas

Comment: Please do not post code and errors as images.

Answer (score 0):

> TBEmployeePc > TBEmployee > EmployeeName (i want get this
> "EmployeeName")

Try:

```
var pc=Octx.TBEmployeePc.Include(x=>x.TBEmployee).ToList();
var namelist = pc.Select(o => o.TBEmployee.Select(c => c.EmployeeName)).ToList();
```